# product type of 2 operands

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have this type:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
using product_type = decltype(::std::declval<T>() * ::std::declval<U>());
```

that I use in a function template

```
template <typename T, typename U>
product_type<T, U> product(T const a, U const b)
{
  return a * b;
}
```

Will the template functions resulting from the template return "reasonable" product values for the C++ fundamental types? I suppose this will use the C++ type promotion rules. Is there a better, more correct way, to return a value of a "reasonable" fundamental type? I am worried I might return a `float` for a product of, say, a `double` and a `float`.

Comment: What do you consider "more correct"?

Comment: That's about the best you can get until C++14's return type deduction.

Comment: More importantly, what do you consider "reasonable"?

Comment: Something that will prevent loss of precision more easily, without the `product_type` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It returns a "reasonable" type, exactly what `a*b` would yield. Your code could also be written as:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto product(T const a, U const b) -> decltype( a * b )
{
    return a * b;
}
```

or with C++14:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto product(T const a, U const b)
{
    return a * b;
}
```

Comment: Also, [`typename std::common_type<T,U>::type product(T const a, U const b)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type)